# How to change default login/lock screen of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

How do I change the default login/lock screen of Windows 8 which is shown after Windows has loaded and no user is logged in? I've changed the lock screen of both users but when Windows starts this one here is always shown

[image: Default login screen]

Another problem I have is that it's displayed in English. I first installed the English version of Windows 8 and afterwards installed the German language pack and made German the primary language. Everything in Windows is now German expect the default login screen.

Comment: please ask *one* question at a time

Comment: Actually the question was about changing the default lock screen which for me at least does not only contain the background image but everything you see there. The language and date/time formatting is part of it _imho_.

Comment: Changing background is explained on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/677600/windows-8-1-default-system-lock-screen-customization/923362#923362

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### How to Change the Default Language

To change the language settings to the Welcome screen, the default lock screen, do the following:

1. Open the Start screen and type `Region`.
2. Select **Settings** as the search area, and
3. Click **Region** on the left pane.
4. Click **Administrative** tab.
   [image: Region settings in Windows 8, Administrative tab]
5. Click **Copy settings** in the **Welcome screen and new user accounts** group.
   You will see the current settings.
6. Select **Welcome screen and system accounts** check box and click **OK** to copy the settings of the current user to the Welcome screen.
   [image: Welcome screen and new user accounts settings]

Since you switched to German language, you have to search for German word Region at step 1.

Alternative way:

1. Click the language on the Taskbar.
2. Then click **Language preferences**.
   [image]
3. Click **Advanced settings** on the right.
4. Click **Apply language setting to the welcome screen, system accounts, and new user accounts** link in the **Override for Windows display language** group.
   It will open **Region** settings with **Administrative** tab selected.
   Follow the steps 5 and 6 from the instructions above.

Comment: Great answer and well hidden setting. I wouldn't have found it ;)

Comment: What about changing the background? Or making any other changes. I feel that this answer is incomplete.

Comment: @MattR I answered only to the part of the question, *language of Login screen*, because changing picture was covered by [another answer](http://superuser.com/a/506062/80304) by Andrew Robinson, and later with [using Group Policy](http://superuser.com/a/611125/80304) by Jaykul.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: Navigate to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\S-1-5-18\ReadOnly\LockScreen_Z\" and replace that picture. You will also need to add permission to "System" to read it.

Let me know how it works.

Comment: Any idea how to change the language? This one even bothers me more.

Comment: Didn't catch that part of the question. Looks like it's answered above :)

Comment: @Sven That's why it's better to ask *only one* question in a post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to set the default lockscreen is the Local Machine setting:

```
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization LockScreenImage "C:\Path\To\Image.png"
```

You can also [set it via Group Policy](http://www.tipsnext.com/windows-8/windows-8-set-default-lock-screen-image/) (depending on your version of Windows):
Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization "Force a specific default lock screen image" ... there's even a matching "Prevent changing lock screen image" if you want to make sure nobody else using your PC can change it.

Answer (score -10):

- Open up the side 'start menu'
- Click on 'Change PC Settings' down the bottom
- 'Personalize'
- 'Browse'
- Choose your picture.

Comment: Doesn't this just change the screen for the current user? Also, please keep your answers respectful and polite.

Comment: This changes the actual 'Lock' screen.  It does not change the 'Logon' screen.  There is a lot of confusion around but the crux is, you can change the Lock screen using my process above.  You can only change the *colour* of the logon screen however.

Comment: So in other words it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: Not sure what question you're reading but here is the original question:

"How do I change the default login/lock screen of Windows 8"

The answer I provided is the best answer for users.  Group Policy, reghax and the rest are unnecessary as M$ have provisioned for this facility......

Comment: You said yourself, "It does not change the 'Logon' screen," and the user wants to change the login screen that you see before anybody has logged in. Ergo, you didn't answer the question.