# Different welcome screen language to system users?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, language, windows-server-2012

Found various articles which can be used to update the system users and login screen via the GUI, such as [How to change default login/lock screen of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/505989/how-to-change-default-login-lock-screen-of-windows-8) but what i need to do is slightly different.

I need the system users to be in Dutch for application and number formatting reasons but i would like for the login screen to appear in English as the vast majority of admins are English.

I appreciate that beyond the login screen the admins will be English and that it is obvious its asking for a user name and password, but the client specifically wants English Login screens, English Language admin user accounts and Dutch language system accounts.

Steps for both WinServer2008r2 and WinServer2012 appreciated, if possible.

Thanks in Advance!
Dave