# Windows 8.1 Welcome Screen Language Malfunction

Tags: windows-8.1, language, start-screen

once I changed my system language to Persian, but after a while I reset the settings back to English and the Country to the US. Though everything is English and the welcome screen settings are also in English, the language on the welcome screen is still Persian when the windows is loaded! How is that possible? How can I fix this? and the weird thing is that, when I set Persian as the main language for everything, the language on the welcome screen becomes English, and when I set English as the main Language, the welcome screen language becomes Persian!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default login/lock screen of Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/505989/how-to-change-default-login-lock-screen-of-windows-8)

Answer (score -1):

It's not as hard as it seems , I'm on Windows 10 but it should be the same on Windows 8 and even Windows 7

1. on Windows 8 , Press `Win`+`Q` to invoke Search.
2. Type `Region` (or equivalent to this in **your language**) .
3. Click on `Administrative` tab.
4. Click `Copy Settings` (might require Admin password if your account is a *standard user*).

In this window you'll see the current language settings for your account and the ones for Welcome Screen as well

5. Click `Welcome screen and system accounts` *checkbox* under `Copy your current settings to:`
6. Click `Ok` and the welcome screen language should now be changed.

Comment: Your missing a step per the duplicate question's answer

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your comment , the above steps should solve the issue? in Windows 10 it works and I don't have access to a windows 8 machine to test it there but I assume it works too.

Comment: I am saying your answer is incomplete.  Your missing a step.