# How to force English when on the Windows 10 lock screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

I know it's possible to set the default language [on the Windows lock screen](https://superuser.com/questions/505989/how-to-change-default-login-lock-screen-of-windows-8) through the Language settings. However after the first login it's possible to switch from English to a second language, lock the screen, and have the lock screen language in a different language.

I would like to force the lock screen to always be English, no matter what language was on before the screen was locked. The reason is my passwords are always in ASCII and occasionally typing in the wrong language is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of researching it seems that this is currently impossible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

See this answer by **bugs_**, works for me: [Per app input language Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1262073/1428096)

You can enable the option:

> "Devices" -> "Typing" -> "Advanced keyboard settings" -> "Let me use a different input method for each app window"

Windows will remeber the langauage you last used on the Lock Screen and it will remain the same the next time you log in.