# Per app input language Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1709

I've set up so that Windows remembers my input language preference for each app, it works really well (US-English as default with Swedish for some apps) until I close the apps/restart the OS, then it forgets and reverts back to English again. Is there a setting to prevent this from happening? I want it to always remember my language preference for each app.

I'm on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update Version 1709 if that matters.

Comment: related, but with no answer too: https://superuser.com/q/1201176/576393

Comment: Ok, but how did you manage do it in the first place? I found several articles and they all shown settings that are not on my Win 10 system at all.

Comment: And it ever worked in any other windows? You probably need an app for that.

Answer (score 35):

In my "Windows 10 Pro" "Version 1809" is not this settings in "Control Panel" anymore.

It is possible to set it in this way:
"Start menu" -> Settings -> Find "Typing settings" -> Advanced keyboard settings -> check checkbox "Let me use a different input method for each app window"

External link:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/102999-turn-off-use-different-keyboard-layout-each-app-window.html

Comment: "Hey, here's something that works and everyone already knows hot to use... let's change it!" how far will Microsoft go to hide this stuff?!?!?!?!

Comment: First 2 steps could be skipped: WinKey and type "Typing settings" -> Advanced keyboard settings -> check checkbox "Let me use a different input method for each app window"

Answer (score 3):

Please try this option, and then set your preference input method for different apps:

Start > Settings > Time & Language > Region & language > Additional date, time & regional settings > (under Language) Change input methods > Advanced settings > (under switching input methods) Check on "Let me set a different input method for each app window"

Comment: Not trying to be rude here but did you even read the question?
I have that set up already and it works very well, until I close the app, then when I open it again, it's reset to English, my question is how do I make it remember when I open the app again?

Comment: This option is set to remember the settings. Did you mean that it didn't work on 1709?

Comment: It works until I close the application, when I open it back up again it has been reset to the default input language. I want it to remember the preferred language for each app even after I restart the computer. If I choose Swedish for all of my messaging apps and then restart the computer, they're all back to English again when I get back into Windows.

Comment: Thanks man, I came to this question because I wanted to find out this. Your answer might not answer the OP, but answered what I hoped to find :D

Comment: works in windows 11

Answer (score 2):

As of 03.12.2020, using **Windows 10 Pro**, the option goes in:

`Settings -> Devices -> Typing -> Advanced Keyboard Settings`

(facepalm)

Answer (score -1):

For 20H2, following **Language** and not **Devices** :

Settings > Time & Language > Language > The **Keyboard icon** at the top.

Makes a bit more sense... but those "STEWPID" borderless buttons are the opposite of intuitive.

Hey Microsoft! You need to fire a lot of people. Some of you programmers (said fast), have no clue how to make GUIs. They make pretty pictures... I'll give you that... but! It strikes me how your interfaces are so "not evident". One has to search all over the place to do things. Not fun anymore.